# Help with finding the surface area of a revolution

Tags: calculus, integration

Here's the problem I'm stuck on:

> Find the surface are of this revolution about the y-axis
>
> $x = \sqrt{9-y^2}; -2\leq y\leq2$

What I've done so far:

$A= 2\pi \int_{-2}^2 \sqrt{9-y^2} \sqrt{1 + (\frac{1}{2}(9-y^2)^\frac{-1}{2}(-2y))^2} dy$

$ = 4\pi \int_{0}^2 \sqrt{9-y^2} \sqrt{1 + (\frac{1}{2}(9-y^2)^\frac{-1}{2}(-2y))^2} dy$

$ = 4\pi \int_{0}^2 \sqrt{(9-y^2) + (9-y^2)(\frac{1}{2}(-2y)(9-y^2)^\frac{-1}{2})^2} dy$

$ = 4\pi \int_{0}^2 \sqrt{(9-y^2) + (9-y^2)((-y)^2(9-y^2)^{-1})} dy$

$ = 4\pi \int_{0}^2 \sqrt{(9-y^2) + (9-y^2)(\frac{(-y)^2}{(9-y^2)})} dy$

$ = 4\pi \int_{0}^2 \sqrt{(9-y^2) + (-y)^2} dy$

$ = 4\pi \int_{0}^2 \sqrt{9-y^2 -y^2} dy$*

$ = 4\pi \int_{0}^2 \sqrt{9-2y^2} dy$

The answer in the book says its:

> $24\pi$

Which means that I needed to get the integral to be:

$ = 4\pi \int_{0}^2 \sqrt{9} dy$

But I just don't see how I can manipulate the problem with algebra to get there... Any guidance?

**EDIT:**

Added in some steps to show where my algrbra went wrong

*This is where I made the mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
& \sqrt{9-y^2} \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{1}{2}(9-y^2)^\frac{-1}{2}(-2y)\right)^2}
= \sqrt{9-y^2} \sqrt{1 + \frac{4y^2}{4(9-y^2)}} \\
& = \sqrt{9-y^2} \sqrt{1 + \frac{y^2}{9-y^2}}
= \sqrt{9-y^2} \sqrt{\frac{(9-y^2) + y^2}{9-y^2}} \\
& = \sqrt{9-y^2} \sqrt{\frac{9}{9-y^2}} = \sqrt{9}.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: It would be nice if you could maybe explain where I went wrong...

Comment: @OghmaOsiris: The calculation that led from your displayed equation $2$ to displayed equation $3$ has a minor algebra error.  Probably did not notice that $(-1)^2=1$.

Comment: @OghmaOsiris: How you got $9 - y^2 -y^2$ is a complete mystery to me.  But I can say that that's where you went wrong.  If I knew how you did it, maybe I could be more specific.

Comment: @AndréNicolas That's it. I redid the problem and I was able to come to the right conclusion after I redid $(-y)^2 = y^2$.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I added more steps and a caveat to help you see my work.

Comment: @OghmaOsiris: As you saw, it was a minor error, essentially a typo. Be careful about parentheses, and don't worry about it. I have undoubtedly made errors of this type many more times than you have.

Comment: So you had $9-y^2 + (-y)^2$.  That's the same as $9-y^2+y^2$, which simplifies to $9$.